# is there any way to hide column in excel and show them automatically when a cell contain a value that I chose?

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help 
is there any way to hide the two column "F" and "G", and show them automatically only whene I chose "Amortissements du véhicule de tourisme" from the liste for example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cbds.png)

Comment: Should be possible with the [worksheet change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: can you explain a little bit, cuz I'm beginner in VBA

Comment: Follow the link above and try to adjust the suggested solution for your file. If you get stuck, explain what you did, what code you have and where you excatly have a problem.

Comment: the difference Sir between my problem and the solution you gave to me, is that in my case I've the whole column "E" not only a cell "A1", the condition must work with the whole column.

Comment: Yes and I just said you need to adjust that solution to your needs. And then I repeat my comment from above _if you get stuck, explain what you did, what code you have and where you excatly have a problem._ And for that you need to open a new post.